# vb.net mysql table normalization and joins

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, string

im trying to read data from my tables, but my reader is not reading below are my tables with there data fields.

> appointment:
>
> ```
> | id | tattooId | date | time | length |
>
> tattoo:
>
> | id | customerID | staffID | description |cost
> ```
>
> customer:
>
> ```
> | id | name | email| address|
> ```
>
> staff:
>
> ```
> | id | name| surname| email|
> ```

the data that i need to get in vb is

> appointment.time  appointment.length tattoo.cost customer.name

I need to fill a list box with appointments, but I want to use appointments for a specific date and a specific staff member. For example, if I picked date 10/03/2015 and staff member "Bob" I need to pull all appointments on that date which correlate to Bob.

at the momment this is my sql statement, when i run it doesnt prompt me with any errors but it doesnt read.

```
    SQLCommand.Connection = SQLconnection

    SQLCommand.CommandText = "SELECT appointment.Time, appointment.Length,tattoo.Cost,customers.customername" & _
                 " FROM appointment" & _
                 " JOIN tattoo ON Appointment.TattooID=tattoo.ID" & _
                 " JOIN staff ON tattoo.StaffID='staff.ID'" & _
                 "JOIN customers ON tattoo.CustomerID='customers.ID'" & _
                 " WHERE appointment.Date='2015-02-06'" & _
                 " AND staff.staffname='" & _staff.Firstname & "';"
```

also if any one knows of a good way to read the data that would be helpfull as some of it is date/time,string, and integers

Comment: `'staff.ID'` is a literal string. It doesn't refer to the staff.ID field. Remove the quotes around that part and the same for `'customer.ID'`

Comment: :P thanks, also do you know what the best method to read the data ?

Comment: It depends on what you have to do. Fill a DataSet or loop using a DataReader are two options. The first method is used to prepare a grid to show your data , the second one is preferable if you need to examine each single record and make decisions on that record's content

Comment: i just need to fill a list box with the data but i guess that be similar to a grid, so a for loop ?

Comment: No, a Listbox has no provision to create separate columns. In your case I would choose a DataGridView and use MySqlDataAdapter to fill a Dataset, then bind the DataSet to the DataGridView and you have your data shown. A [tutorial can be found here](http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_binding.htm), it is for Sql Server but it is easy to adapt for MySql (just change the class types and keep your connection string)

Comment: I'd also say use parameters instead of strings from textboxes for avoiding characters causing errors among other things:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp